# PHP session handler storing session as JSON not decoding php serialize correctly

Tags: php, json, session, serialization, amazon-dynamodb

I've implemented a session handler using DynamoDB. It is working correctly, except for when the response is returned from the server and I call `json_decode` on it, the nested php serialized session string is broken. I assume storing a serialized session inside a JSON object is not compatible? Is this an escaping issue?

Questions:

1. Is there a way to get around this?
2. Is it possible to serialize the session in JSON rather than php `serialize()` which I assume is used? This would probably solve the issue.

This is how the original looks when it comes from the DB (note: it's really long so I've cut the end off myself)

```
_sf2_attributes|a:4:{s:34:"_security.secured_area.target_path";s:36:"http://my.domain";s:10:"some_id";s:13:"abc123";s:8:"userData";O:27:"Some\Symfony\Bundle":49:{s:8:"�*�email";s:27:"
```

This is how it looks after calling `json_decode` on the JSON object this string is inside:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:4:{s:34:"_security.secured_area.target_path";s:36:"http://my.domain";s:10:"some_id";s:13:"abc123";s:8:"userData";O:27:"Some\Symfony\Bundle":49:{s:8:"
```

It appears to be truncated where the asterisk is in the original.

Comment: If it's serialized, you should use `unserialize()` to decode it, not `json_decode()`.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: The php session is automatically serialized into whatever the format that php uses is. I then store it in DynamoDB which uses JSON, so I have a json object which contains a php session. When I call json_decode, it gives me everything as an array, but the session string is truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json and serialization works fine in PHP

```
class ClassA
    {
    public $publicMember;
    private $privateMember;
    protected $protected;
    }
$object = new ClassA();
var_dump(unserialize(json_decode(json_encode(serialize($object)))));
```

But this issue could come from [DynamoDB: Bug in DynamoDB / DynamoDB Session Handler for PHP (handling of NULL BYTES)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94935). It seems that it closed, but... you could add additional wrap with [base64_encode](http://php.net/base64_encode) before json_encode

```
var_dump(unserialize(base64_decode(json_decode(json_encode(base64_encode(serialize($object)))))));
```

Comment: Encoding with base64 worked. I'll do some more research into why it's failing without base64.

Comment: That bug was specific to Version 1 of the AWS SDK for PHP, because it used SimpleXML for everything. Version 2 does not. However, the null bytes definitely seem to be where the issue is happening.

Comment: Where are you applying the base64 encoding?

Comment: @jeremy - I attempted encoding where the session data is passed to the write method: `$this->sessionHandler->write($sessionId, base64_encode($data));` then in the read method decoding it. It seems to solve the issue but it feels hacky. I'd love to try and help pinpoint the exact cause. I've opened a thread in the forum if you want to discuss there: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162309&tstart=0

Comment: Cool. I'll take a deeper look at this, but probably not until late next week.